# Is there an exteded switch role for Azure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, cloud

I have been using extended switch roles on AWS. Now I want to use a similar functionality or extension for Azure also. I searched on web but did not find much regarding this. Following is the link to the chrome extension as follows:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aws-extend-switch-roles/jpmkfafbacpgapdghgdpembnojdlgkdl?hl=en